# Get ContextMenu item ID

Tags: android, database, contextmenu, android-contentprovider, android-cursor

I have a simple layout where there are few textviews. Here what I do is define a name, and save it into a database using a contentProvider. Then, this name is read from the database and shown on the textView.

This is how I first get the item saved on the database:

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(TravelersProvider.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, null);
```

The projection is:

```
String[] PROJECTION = {Travelers._ID, Travelers.NAME};
```

Now What I need to do is:

- Create contextMenu for when I click on the textview with the name, I can edit or delete it.

This is the way I register the contextMenu to the TextView:

```
txtView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        registerForContextMenu(v);
    }
});
```

Then I create it:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}
```

And finally I define what to do when touching:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //TODO:
}
```

Here is where I need some help. Basically, what I need to do is:

- Define wich element is the one that I've touched. This should obtain an index.
- Get the cursor and move it to that position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `onCreateContextMenu` hook, there is a `View` parameter.  Call `getId()` on this parameter to determine which TextView invoked the context menu.  Then you can store this into a class variable to be used in `onContextItemSelected`.

```
private int contextViewId;

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    contextViewId = v.getId();
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // use contextViewId
}
```

Comment: Some questions... what is `contextViewId`? String? Int? Also, about the other thing, I have done something similar to this but using a ResourceCursorAdapter with a listview, and when I wanted to get the cursor int the  `onContextItemSelected` this is what did: `Cursor cursor = mCursorAdapter.getCursor();` `cursor.moveToPosition(itemPos);` But now, as I'm not using any adapter, how can I get the cursor to move it to the position?

Comment: `contextViewId` is the (integer) id of the View that the context menu was created for.  This is how you know which TextView the user clicked on.  As for your Cursor, you've already shown us how you create the Cursor in your first code example.  Just call `c.moveToPosition`.  I don't know how you can get the database id from the TextView though, you haven't given us enough information.